# JPA ManyToMany retreive 2 lists in one query

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many

I need your help.

I've 2 tables with a join table to get ManyToMany relationship as below :

[Table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ4uv.png)

In JAVA with JPA, I'm able for one User to get `List<Group>`, or for a Group to get `List<User>`.

Is there a way to get one entity with `List<User>` AND `List<Group>` like you can do with SQL :

```
SELECT * FROM USER_GROUP 
INNER JOIN USERS ON USERS.ID = USER_GROUP.USER_ID 
INNER JOIN GROUPS ON GROUPS.ID = USER_GROUP.GROUP_ID 
WHERE USERS.USER_NAME LIKE ....
```

Thx all for your help :)

Comment: In your query you select all user_groups filtered by user_name, so if you enable fetch type EAGER for the related list of users, you should get a similar query and load all relevant data,  But you need to provide the code of your entity classes and tell if you have any issues.